# Can Java self-modify via user input?

Tags: java, theory

I'm interested in an executed script allowing user input to modify the process and corresponding source.

What precedents exist to implement such a structure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, depending on what is meant.

Consider such projects as [ObjectWeb ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) (see the [the ASM 2.0 tutorial](http://asm.ow2.org/doc/tutorial-asm-2.0.html) for a general rundown).

Trying to emit the-would-need-to-be-decompiled Java source code is another story: if this was the goal then perhaps the source should be edited, re-compiled, and somehow loaded in/over. (This is possible as well, consider tools like [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/).)

Happy coding.

Comment: So at worst it can recompile and run a new session. Anything better? I'd think it could instead recompile once at end of session and only modify the active process until then.

Comment: "At worst" :) If JRebel still has a trial, I'd recommend playing with that. It doesn't give the code/API, oh what an awesome thing that would be, but you can see new[ly compiled] classes being loaded "on the fly". Now, imagine that if instead of a programmer updating the class source... (There are tools to deal with Java sourcecode/ASTs as well).

Comment: @user474632 If this is purely an academic adventure, however, I think much more immediate gains would result from playing with a [LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lisp_%28programming_language%29) implementation. LISP has advantages here, such as a built-in eval, and a code-is-just-data mindset. LISP arguably introduced the entire concept of meta-programming -- back the 50s!

Comment: Thanks ever-so-much for the Wikipedia link, I shortly thereafter found the page on self-hosting, which does indeed include Java among a list of self-hosting languages.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be able to modify existing classes.  But if you implement a ClassLoader then you can dynamically load classes from non-traditional sources:  network, XML file, user input, random number generator, etc.

There are probably other, better ways.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Java scripting API is what you're looking for:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/script/package-summary.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an app once that used reflection to allow tests to be driven by a text file.  For instance, if you had a class like this:

```
class Tuner(String Channel) {

    tune(){...
    play(){...
    stop(){...
}
```

You could execute methods via code like:

```
tuner=Channel 1
tune tuner
play tuner
stop tuner
```

It had some more capabilities (You could pass objects into other objects, etc), but mostly I used it to drive tests on a cable box where a full write/build/deploy in order to test took on the order of a half hour.

You could create a few reusable classes and tie them together with this test language to make some very complex and easy to create tests.

THAT is a DSL, not monkeying around with your loose-syntax language by eliminating parenthesis and adding underscores and dots in random locations to make it look like some strange semi-English.